# Android: transfer byte array with AIDL

Tags: android, aidl

I need to transfer byte array between an Android service and client. I have tried to define an aidl interface like:

```
interface IMyService {
    int putBytes(String key, in List<Byte> bytes);
    int getBytes(String key, out List<Byte> bytes);    
}
```

But, it doesn't compile. The error is:

```
[aidl] E:\workspace\RAMService\src\com\connexis\service\mem\IRAMService.aid
l:14 parameter bytes (2) unknown type List<Byte>
```

Could someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10):

Try using byte[] instead of List, it works for me.

```
interface IMyService {
    int putBytes(String key, in byte[] bytes);
    int getBytes(String key, out byte[] bytes);    
}
```

AIDL only support primitives, String, CharSequence, List, Map. You can have List but never List

[AIDL doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like its described here: [Transfering ByteArray through Parcel returns NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708945/tranfering-bytearray-through-parcel-returns-nullpointerexception)

This is example of how to transfer byte array by wrapping it in Parcelable interface.
I think you can do the same with List