# parcelable ArrayList passed partially with null elements

Tags: android, arraylist, parcelable

when i pass an array between intents as a result to startActivityForResult
I get a partial array back

```
ArrayList<User> currentUsers = ...

Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(USER_ARR, currentUsers);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);

ArrayList<User> users = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(USER_ARR);
```

User implements Parcelable, and it is built correct for sure,

I changed something in the passing of the array and now when it sends the array

it is received on other side with many users being null, or all but one user being null

I also tried sending just a Parcelable[], and that did the same thing

please help

Comment: Change of using `Serializable` instead of `Parcelable` is an option?, I t can be an easier solution

Comment: yeah, but it that is not my question though, it is already a parcelable and it did work like that in the past, so it should still work, please anyone??

Comment: Can you post more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer :)
I have no idea how it worked before fixing this

I was reading a byte array inside my parcelable 
only if the size of the byte array was bigger than zero,
but not reading it did not advance the dataPosition()

thanks to this question [Make custom Parcelable containing byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898116/make-custom-parcelable-containing-byte-array) I found the answer

have a great day everybody