# ArrayList pass a null using Bundle

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Currently I have an ArrayList that I wanted to pass to another activity. I've already applied `getParcelableArrayList`but it pass null to another activity. I've check the array for null, it's not. In the current activity before I pass it at least.

This is my code:

`RecyclerViewOffline.java`

```
Toast.makeText(context,"Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),OfflineActivity.class);

Log.d("Contexts Test : ", fileContents.get(holder.getLayoutPosition()).getTitle());

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//bundle.putParcelableArrayList("link",fileContents);
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("ArrayList",fileContents);
bundle.putInt("position",holder.getLayoutPosition());

intent.putExtra("bundle",bundle);
view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

My receiving end:

`OfflineActivity.java`

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getBundleExtra("bundle");

 if(extras != null) {
   this.fileContents = extras.getParcelableArrayList("ArrayList");
   layoutPosition = extras.getInt("position");
   Log.d("Contexts Test Offline: ",""+ fileContents.get(layoutPosition).getTitle());
    }
 else{}
```

Comment: Which type of item `fileContents` contain ?

Comment: What happens when you do this : `getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("fileContents")`

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469267/parcelable-arraylist-passed-partially-with-null-elements/18505607#18505607)

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK fileContents contain an object.

Comment: @MohamadAzrie: that object is `Parcelable` ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK it's a class where I implements `Parcelable`. But I did recently add another ArrayList in that class object where I pass it to another activity. Could that be the problem ?

Comment: @MohamadAzrie did you added that arraylist to the parcelable contructor and in and out methods

Comment: @ColdFire It seems that I didn't specify it in my parcelable constructor and in an out methods. Thank you for pointing it out. Do you mind putting that as the answer ? Thanks.

Comment: @MohamadAzrie done please accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see

You didnt add the arraylist in the Parcelable in and out method and contructor.

This will solve your issue.